# Regex Pattern that has to include something after /

Tags: regex

Using Regex, I want to match any URL that includes the `/it-jobs/` but must have something after the final `/`.

To be a match the URL must have `/it-jobs/` + characters after the trailing `/` otherwise it should not match. Please refer to below example.

Example: `www.website.com/it-jobs/` - is not a match 
`www.website.com/it-jobs/java-developer` - is a match
`www.website.com/it-jobs/php` - is a match
`www.website.com/it-jobs/angular-developer` - is a match

Comment: What about `GET` parameters? Would `.../it-jobs/?key=value` be a match?

Comment: @Rogue that scenario is not possible in the way this was developed, but as per regex yes, that would be a matching case.

Comment: If you need a concrete answer please add **all** pattern requirements in a verbal form in the question. We cannot help until you come up with what you need. I suggested `/it-jobs/[^/\s]+$` that only matches `/it-jobs/` and then *any one or more chars **other than** ``/`` **and whitespaces***. If that is what you need add these requirements to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried to provide more clarity, but I don't think I can't be more specific. I do not need ```/it-jobs/``` to match as in the example provided.

Comment: And what I suggested - https://regex101.com/r/zyKQrL/3 - does not match `/it-jobs/`. It was downvoted, so considered not helpful. No idea what will be until you explain it clearer than " I do not need `/it-jobs/` to match". Best way is to describe what you want to match, this is what regex is for.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but i described it - to be a match it must contain ```/it-jobs/``` + characters after the trailing ```/```. What is not clear? I even provided examples of what should be a match and not a match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex works :) but just one more question. In order to match the text before the first ```/``` do we need to add anything to your regex, so that for example the all ```www.website.com/it-jobs/java-developer``` is a match?

Comment: Add `.*` to match any text. I undeleted my answer so that we can finalize the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/it-jobs/[^/\s]+$
```

To match the whole string, add `.*` at the pattern start:

```
.*/it-jobs/[^/\s]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zyKQrL/5).

*Details*:

- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `/it-jobs/` - a literal string
- `[^/\s]+` - any one or more chars other than `/` and whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there shouldn't be any whitespaces after "/". My point here is that it must have characters after the "/it-jobs/" path.

Comment: @PauloBrás My regex does not allow any whitespaces after `/it-jobs/`, why are you even mentioning it? Did you test it?